# Prerequisites for building a custom Windows 10 IoT Image?

Tags: iot, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I just started working with the Windows 10 IoT Core on my Raspberry Pi 2. It is great and I enjoy it. But there is one thing: I want to get rid of all these pre-installed apps and other things. I want to create my custom image so to say. There is a nice article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn916104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it somehow doesn't work for me.

I can't select the "**The Windows image is based on Microsoft packages**" option in the "**Select imaging source format**" dialog. Why? I installed everything correctly.

---

EDIT: According to [this new blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iot/2015/12/14/windows-10-iot-core-image-creation/) I need to install the Windows ADK (done) and the IoT Package (done - The Raspberry Pi 2 Tools). And it also says:

*"When these installations are complete, directories called FMFiles, MSPackages, and OEMInputSamples will exist in your development computer’s C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10 directory."*

No for me :( I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to sign in on this page

https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/

To accept the commercial terms and receive the license terms.

Then, to create your images, read this blog post called "Windows 10 IoT Core Image Creation"

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iot/2015/12/14/windows-10-iot-core-image-creation/

You will need to use the Windows 10 Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) and the Windows 10 IoT Core OS Packages

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. But this still doesn't resolve my problem (can't select option in Imaging Tool: "Select imaging source format") :/

Comment: What do you mean by imaging tool ?

Comment: The  Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer. I can't execute step 4 because the option “The Windows image is based on Microsoft packages” is greyed out. I can't choose it. It says I need to install Microsoft Packages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes looks like you can!

Check this out for details on commercialization process:
https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/

Comment: Yes I know this side. But it doesn't help in any way. The first link sends me an email with the End user license and the second button shows me distributors. This is not what I consider being a normal "user".

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iot/2015/12/14/windows-10-iot-core-image-creation/